# How would I remove words from dictionary key lists that contain 6 or more letters?

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to create a function that is able to remove words with less than 6 characters from each list that is a value of a key of a dictionary.

I'm trying to pop each word that is less than 6 out of the list but I'm getting "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object". I don't know if the method I am using is correct.

```
def remove_word(words_dict):
    items_list = list(words_dict.items())

    for key, value in range(len(items_list) -1, -1, -1):
        if len(value) < 6:
            items_list.pop()
    words_dict = items_list.sort()
    return words_dict
```

```
words_dict = {'colours' : ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    'places' : ['america', 'china', 'malaysia', 'argentina', 'india'],
    'animals' : ['lion', 'cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'monkey',
                'zebra'],
    }
```

Should print:

```
1.
colours : []
places : ['america', 'malaysia', 'argentina']
animals : ['monkey']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest way, this is not an effective way to do it, but it is readable and I wrote it this way so you can see the logic for it to work

```
 In [23]: def remove_word(my_dict):
    ...:     for key in my_dict:
    ...:         to_delete = []
    ...:         for values in my_dict[key]:
    ...:             if len(values) < 6:
    ...:                 to_delete.append(values)
    ...:         for word in to_delete:
    ...:             my_dict[key].remove(word)
    ...:     return my_dict
    ...:
    ...:
```

It will give you the desired output

```
In [26]: remove_word(words_dict)
Out[26]:
{'colours': [],
 'places': ['america', 'malaysia', 'argentina'],
 'animals': ['monkey']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# input data
words_dict = {'colours' : ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    'places' : ['america', 'china', 'malaysia', 'argentina', 'india'],
    'animals' : ['lion', 'cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'monkey',
                'zebra'],
    }
# creating a final output dictionary 

#looping through each key value pair present in dictionary and adding the key 
# the final dictionary and processed valeus to the corresponding key
# using lambda function, fast readable and easy to understand 
result = {k:list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>=6, v)) for k,v in words_dict.items()}
print(result)
```

output

```
    {'colours': [], 'places': ['america', 'malaysia', 'argentina'], 'animals': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nested loops:

```
for key in words_dict:
    words_dict[key] = [i for i in dict[key] if len(i) >= 6]
```

A loop comprehension (building a new list based on criteria from the previous list) is actually the easiest way to accomplish this task, because of how python handles list iterators. You can actually put that inside a dict comprehension as well:

```
new_words_dict = {key: [i for i in value if len(i) >= 6] for key, value in words_dict.items()}
```

Comment: This won't work, you need to use `words_dict.items()` and OP is popping items `< 6` so `len(i)` needs to be `>= 6` or `> 5` to follow their original stipulations.

Comment: @Jab thanks for your corrections. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a loop over the dict and a nested comprehension.

```
words_dict = {
    'colours' : ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    'places' : ['america', 'china', 'malaysia', 'argentina', 'india'],
    'animals' : ['lion', 'cat', 'dog', 'wolf', 'monkey','zebra'],
}

for key, lst in words_dict.items():
    filtered_lst = [word for word in lst if len(word) >= 6]
    print(f"{key} : {filtered_lst}")
```

Output for this is:

```
colours : []
places : ['america', 'malaysia', 'argentina']
animals : ['monkey']
```

Or to actually make a function that essentially removes the elements and returns the corrected dict as your code originally did then use something as follows:

```
def remove_words(words_dict):
    return {key: [word for word in lst if len(word) >= 6] 
            for key, lst in words_dict.items()}
```

But then you'd still need to loop over them to print it correctly.

```
words_dict = remove_words(words_dict)
for key, lst in words_dict.items():
    print(f"{key} : {lst}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`{k: [i for i in v if len(i) > 5] for k, v in words_dict.items()}`